# Ajax refreshing page without reloading doubles the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is the ajax code I used and I call it everytime I clicked a row in a table.

```
function loadPage() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("view").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
              }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "userTable.php", true);
        xhttp.send();         
    }
```

the data changes whenever I clicked each row which is what I want. But the moment I clicked a row, the contents of my page (textfields, tables, button, etc) are doubled. Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: if it's doubling up, you must be getting double responses in `responseText`

Comment: @JaromandaX can you tell me how could I fix it? I searched for it but can't find the ones with doouble responses.

Comment: no, because I can't see what's coming back - only you can see that

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "userTable.php?selEmp="+value,

        success: function (response) {

        $("#userBody").html(response);
        setInformation();

        }
});
```

this is what I used instead of the other one :)